# How to keep alive a long-running connection on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, sidekiq

I am scraping a web page with 1M data. I am using `Nokogiri`, `Watir` and `Sidekiq`. It's a long-running connection like 5 hours. Because of that, I prefer to use queueing with `Sidekiq`. 
However, I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

The problems I have:

1. Like 30 minutes after I start a `job`, the system itself starts a new `job`. Both of them seems to be running. What is that a new `job?` Is it a new from scratch or remain part of the first `job?` Because I don't start a `new job.`
2. When I check the `sidekiq` `log` file, I see :

```
TID-nz9ss WARN: Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
WARN: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/redis-4.1.2/lib/redis/client.rb:362:in `rescue in establish_connection'
```

right after the error, I have this:

```
Redis is online, 3.072998513991479 sec downtime
TID-nz91k INFO: Redis is online, 3.07191184500698 sec downtime
TID-nz9ss INFO: Redis is online, 3.071773702016799 sec downtime
```

Is it crashing or continuing the same process ?

I also changed the following:

I made `Watir's` `default timeout to 300000000`.

I made `passenger_max_pool_size 0`.

I added `4GB swap` memory to my `VPS`.

Is there a better way to do this? Thoughts?

Comment: check your redis is start as 6379 port

Comment: its working on start.

Comment: You say it's running the job and then starts running another job -- have you checked the see if they're the same job? Look at your logs, you'll see something like `JID-3c3b6fdcfcd1083595a4756b INFO: start`. `JID-xxx` is the job id of the job stored in Redis, so if you see that same line 30 minutes later when the second job starts then you'll know for certain it's the same job running twice.

Comment: JID's are different. But I don't have any action to start another job.

Comment: I found that my `chromedriver` is crashing after a while. But I still don't understand that is it related to `Redis` connection problem or restart?

Comment: can't you split this into several small jobs? if not sidekiq is a wrong tool for your job. in that case you need a microservice like seperate process. consider rabbitmq.